# Android Webview : detecting when page has rendered

Tags: android, webview

I am writing a highbred Android app that uses a lot of webviews.  The problem is that the onPageFinished event for a webview is fired when a page is loaded but may not be rendered yet.

I believe there was a onNewPicture but has been removed since version 12.

Has anyone come across the same issue, my spinner basically disappears about 3-4 seconds before the page is actually rendered.

Comment: What has your spinner to do with it? Where is that spinner?

Comment: Sorry, so as the page loads I display a loading spinner, I then want to hide this once the page has rendered (as opposed to loaded)

Comment: Are you implying that this happens because pictures have to be loaded yet after onpagefinished? Or is this page doing yet other stuff?

Comment: I am not really sure, I assume it javascript libraries loading in to member.  We dont have control over the web pages.  the page finish loading according to the event about 2-3 seconds later it renders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rendering of a WebView can take a long time for long documents, and indeed [onNewPicture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.PictureListener.html) has been deprecated since API 12 (Honeycomb 3.1) and returns a null picture since API level 18 (Jellybean 4.3).

I have tested for API level 17 (JB 4.2), and it still works fine. Probably works fine in API 18 too if you don't need the actual `Picture` details.

Please this issue on [the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38646) so we can get a non-deprecated replacement.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        PictureListener pictureListener = new PictureListener() {
            @Override
            @Deprecated
            public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Picture changed!");
            }

        };
        webView.setPictureListener(pictureListener);
}
```

Comment: I was using this method for a while. Now, I detected that this method called four times and more.